# Expected number of coins taken by a pirate (problem with rounding)

Tags: probability

We have N number of coins in a chest

Two pirates are in a queue to take coins of the chest.

When we draw some coins, the probabilities are all equal, so ${1,2,3....,k}$ all have the same probability where k is the current number of coins available in the chest.

Let's say we have 10 coins, and 2 pirates

Now we can easily see that for the first pirate we can expect the number of coins to be the average of the currently available so:

$(1+10)/2 = 5.5 $

Since we are dealing with integers, that means the expected number of coins for the first pirate is 5 (Am I correct here?)

Now for the second pirate, should I consider the expected number of coins to be:

Round the remaining after the first pick, so remaining = (10 - 5.5) = 4.5

which means: Second pick = $Round( (1 + 4.5)/2 )$

or:

Take the remaining after the first pick after rounding the outcome of the first pick, so remaining = 10 - 5 = 5

which means: Second pick = $Round((1+ 5)/2)$

In my opinion it should be the first one.

Also in later picks, for example the fifth one, do I have to round each time until I reach the fifth one or just round the result, or round the remaining of the fourth step?

Comment: You should not do any rounding at all. There is nothing wrong with the expected number of coins not being an integer.

Comment: Just because you are dealing with integer quantities doesn't mean the expected value will be an integer. Take a coin toss where you win \$1 on a head, and win \$0 on a tail, then the expected winnings will be \$0.50.

Comment: Expected doesn't mean most likely, it's just the average. So nothing requires the average of integers to be an integer.

Comment: Also, you can't simply assume that the first pirate drew any number. Rather, you have to do an analysis of each case - the probability that pirate $2$ draws $7$ is $\frac{1}{10}\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{10}\frac 1 8+\frac{1}{10} \frac 1 7$. That's going to be a little harder to analyze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first pirate draws $1$, then the second pirate expects to draw $5$.
If the first pirate draws $2$, then the second pirate expects to draw $4.5$.

In general, if the first pirate draws $k$, then the second pirate expects to draw $\frac{10-k+1}{2}$. The case where pirate $1$ gets $10$ is different - then pirate $2$ gets zero.

Since the first pirate's options are all equally likely, the expected number drawn by pirate $2$ is the average of $5,4.5,4.0,3.5,3.0,2.5,2.0,1.5,1.0,0$. The average here is $2.7$.

If there were $n$ coins in the pile, then pirate $2$ would expect $\frac{n+1}{4}-\frac{1}{2n}$ which, when $n$ is large, is close to exactly half of the expected number of coins for pirate $1$.

This is all after the first pick. The general problem requires you to set up a recurrence relationship.

Comment: What is wrong with this:
Average of first pick = (1+10)/2 = 5.5
Then average of the second pick = (1+4.5)/2 = 2.75

You say it's 2.7 but if I do it this way I get 2.75, I just can't see why this is the case.

I have done a small simulation, and actually the correct number is 2.7 ....

Comment: The problem is that the first pirate doesn't pick $5.5$, he picks somewhere from $1$ to $10$. On average, he gets $5.5$, it is true, but it is a misunderstanding of probability to assume that this means you can treat the second question "as if" the first pirate got $5.5$. If you do that, you will in other problems get a lot worse error than $0.05$. Essentially, this is a question of "dependent probabilities."

Comment: Probability would be a lot easier if it worked the way you want it to. It is unfortunately not that simple.

Comment: Ok I think I understand now, it's the first time I come across this.
One more question though, how did you get the formula  $\frac{n+1}{4}-\frac{1}{2n}$ for the second pirate?

Comment: Assuming the first pirate took $k$ with $k<n$, then there are $n-k$ coins left, so pirate $2$ expects to tae $\frac{n-k+1}{2}$. We need the average of that set of values, and $0$ when $k=n$. That can be written as:$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{n-k+1}{2}$$ If you know how to sum an arithmetic sequence, you are done.

Comment: thank you so much that was really helpful, I understand it now